# .htaccess RewriteRule directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ ./view.php?id=$1
```

This works if say an id = "abc123", I can access `www.site.com/abc123` perfectly fine.

But I want to be able to access with `www.site.com/view/abc123`

So I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)/?$ ./view.php?id=$1
```

But to no avail. When I try to access `www.site.com/view/abc123` it seems as if it doesn't even grab the `$_GET` request to get the id.
What's wrong?

My entire .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/sitetest/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^view/(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

Edit:

Using the above .htaccess, when I access:
`http://localhost/~user/sitetest/view/abc123`

It doesn't load the $_GET[] from view.php. I even tried echoing out $_GET[] but it shows up as blank.

If I edit it to be `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1`
And access `http://localhost/~user/sitetest/abc123` it works fine.

If I edit it to be `RewriteRule ^view-(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1`
And access `http://localhost/~user/sitetest/view-abc123` it works fine.

Does it have something to do with the slash??

Comment: check my comment on my own post, can't edit it yet to notify you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# this next line is really important
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

Using RewriteBase, you are specifically telling the server to use view.php in the server's root. If you don't specify the RewriteBase, the server will use the view.php in the requested directory (being /view/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This didn't work either :( I'm doing it on localhost if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Aaron can you post the rest of your .htaccess file? Maybe there is something else screwing things up :)

Comment: Edited my main post. Hopefully it's an easy fix!

Comment: I don't see any errors in the posted .htaccess, the only think that MAY be wrong is the RewriteBase. Make sure the path you specify there is relative to the htdocs directory of your site's document root. So just try changing it to `RewriteBase /` for a second and see if it works.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :( I edited my main post again with a more in-depth explanation of what I'm seeing.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the slash affecting either the condition or the base.. I edited my post even further with a better explanation. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6142/discussion-between-tom-knapen-and-aaron)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `/` at the start of the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^/view/(.*)$ /view.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I had /? in there so it would ideally work with urls that had a trailing slash.

Comment: not sure where the problem is, so trying different approach plus the .* would eat the trailing slash anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting RewriteBase to / and using /~user/... in my RewriteRule
(creds to Tom Knapen, posting here because of code-example).

So, OP's .htaccess would become:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^view/(.+?)/?$ /~user/sitetest/view.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
<IfModule !rewrite_module>
    ErrorDocument 404 /home/user/public_html/sitetest/view.php
    #OR perhaps:
    #ErrorDocument 404 /home/user/httpdocs/sitetest/view.php
</IfModule>
```